# Recommended web UI component for geoplotting in browser?

Tags: open-source, javascript, maps, user-interface

I am looking for a backend-independent UI component which allows drawing and plotting simple maps and some overlay information like dots.

It should up-to-date (= work with recent major browsers, desktop is sufficient), be well supported/have some community footprint, free and open source. Ideally jQuery.

So far, I can find [mapael](https://github.com/neveldo/jQuery-Mapael) which is a good candidate pretty close to the above requirements, though it has some issues and there has been no new release since 2018.

Other suggestions?